# How to migrate PivotalTracker user stories to Github issues?

Tags: github, github-api, pivotaltracker

Is there any beautiful and easy way to migrate all the user stories from Pivotal Tracker to GitHub Issues?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i found solution for myself and made some compilation here:
https://github.com/Bazai/pivotal2github